# EF Core Timestamp error when running SqlLite Integration Tests

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

Per this articke: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/testing/sqlite, I'm trying to Test using Sqlite provider. (In memory works fine). One of my columns is a Timestamp column:

```
[Timestamp]
public byte[] Timestamp { get; set; }
```

which works fine when using **options.UseSqlServer()**. However, when I run a test with this configuration:

```
_connection = new SqliteConnection("DataSource=:memory:");   
_connection.Open();

_options = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<BuyGroupDataContext>()
     .UseSqlite(_connection)                                          
     .Options;

...
var bg = GenerateGroup();
bg.Timestamp = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(DateTime.Now.ToString());

using (var context = new GroupDataContext(_options))
{
    context.Groups.Add(bg);
    context.SaveChanges(); // fails here
}
```

Error:

> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbUpdateException : An error occurred
>   while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details.
>   ---- Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteException : SQLite Error 19: 'NOT NULL constraint failed: Group.Timestamp'.

Comment: what datatype is `Group.Timestamp` in sql? debug and check if there is a value. `Not Null` exception is raised.

Comment: (Timestamp, not null)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved my problem by adding:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    ...

    modelBuilder.Entity<Entities.BuyGroup>().Property(o => o.Timestamp)
        .IsRowVersion()
        .HasDefaultValueSql("CURRENT_TIMESTAMP");

    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
}
```

to OnModelCreating method to my DataContext class

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you use Timestamp for row versionning rigth ? If your are in optimitic concurrency, don't forget to configure your entity like :

```
public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<T> builder)
{
    builder.Property(prop => prop.Timestamp).IsRowVersion();
{
```

see more [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-mvc/concurrency?view=aspnetcore-3.1#add-a-tracking-property)

Comment: didn't work. what should be populated in Timestamp field for tests?